# Css grid layout no me acaba de funcionar correctamente

Tags: html, css, css-grid-layout

¡Hola a todos!

Estoy haciendo un ecommerce para un proyecto de clase y me he animado a utilizar el diseño grid de css para que sea algo más responsive, la cosa es que cuando lo pongo en móvil con la funcionalidad del navegador, los productos no se me ponen uno encima del otro, sino que siguen como si no funcionara, es raro porqué si redimensiono la ventana del navegador estando en modo desktop, sí que se me ponen bien los productos y si no hay mucho espacio y demás se me bajan y funciona correctamente.
Por otro lado, el título y la foto, en móvil, deberían de salir uno al lado debjo del otro y en escritorio uno al lado del otro y centrados.

¿Alguien puede echarme un cable?

Código HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/emarket-favicon.png">
    <title>Electronic Market</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <!-- CAPÇALERA -->
      <div class="row">
        <div id="header" class="col-12">
          <div id="logo">
            <img src="img/business-logo.png" alt="Logo"/>
            <a href="index.php">
              <h1>Electronic Market</h1>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- MENU -->
      <div class="row">
        <div id="menu" class="col-12">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Inici</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Cat 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Cat 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Cat 3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- CONTINGUT -->
      <div id="content" class="row">
        <!-- BARRA LATERAL -->
        <div id="lateral" class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
          <div id="login" class="block_aside col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <form action="#" method="post">
              <label for="email">Email</label>
              <input type="email" name="email"/>
              <label for="password">Contrasenya</label>
              <input type="password" name="password"/>
              <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
            </form>
            <a href="#">Mis pedidos</a>
            <a href="#">Gestionar pedidos</a>
            <a href="#">Gestionar categorias</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- CONTINGUT CENTRAL -->
        <div id="central" class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
          <!-- TÍTOL -->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <h1>Feature Products</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- PRODUCTES -->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="product col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <img src="img/emarket-favicon.png"/>
              <h2>PC GAMER</h2>
              <p>900€</p>
              <a href="#">Comprar</a>
            </div>
            <div class="product col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <img src="img/emarket-favicon.png"/>
              <h2>iPad Pro</h2>
              <p>650€</p>
              <a href="#">Comprar</a>
            </div>
            <div class="product col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <img src="img/emarket-favicon.png"/>
              <h2>Huawei Watch 2000</h2>
              <p>350€</p>
              <a href="#">Comprar</a>
            </div>
            <div class="product col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <img src="img/emarket-favicon.png"/>
              <h2>iPhone 11 256GB</h2>
              <p>1.500€</p>
              <a href="#">Comprar</a>
            </div>
          </div>   
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- PEU DE PÀGINA -->
      <div class="row">
        <div id="footer" class="col-12">
          <p>Desenvolupat per Alex Iglesias i Isaac Labuena &copy; <?=date("Y") ?></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Código CSS:

```
/* GENERAL*/

*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

body{
    background: url(../img/fondo1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;

}

a {
    color: #01b1ea;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited{
    color: #01b1ea;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover{
    color: #555;
}

.container{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px gray;
}

/* CAPÇALERA */

#header{
    background: #f0f0f0;
}

#logo{
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

#logo img {
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
}

#logo a{
    float: left;
    font-size: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #01b1ea;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 18px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 1px #222222;
    transition: all 300ms;
}

#logo a:hover{
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 1px #222222, 0px 0px 4px #01b1ea;
}

/* MENU */



.product img {
    width: 100px;
}

/* CONTINGUT CENTRAL */

#content{
    background: white;
}
```

Estructura de carpetas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto proyecto en un link (no es ningún virus ni nada):

https://anonfile.com/Z2Z1x318o2/emarket_rar

Y así queda en telf, como veis los productos no se me ponen uno encima del otro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano.

**EDIT1: 20/05/2020 21:51h.**

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/emarket-favicon.png">
    <title>Electronic Market</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <!-- CAPÇALERA -->
      <div class="row">
        <div id="header" class="col-12">
          <div id="logo" class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <a href="index.php"><img src="img/business-logo.png" alt="Logo"/></a>
          </div>
          <div id="text-logo" class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
            <a href="index.php">
              <h1 class="h1-logo">Electronic Market</h1>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- MENU -->
      <div class="row">
        <nav id="menu" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg sticky-top navbar-dark bg-dark">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">PC's</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link " href="#">Smartphones</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link " href="#">Tablets</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link " href="#">Smartwatches</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <!-- CONTINGUT -->
      <div id="content" class="row">
        <!-- BARRA LATERAL -->

        <div id="lateral" class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <div id="login" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <form action="/examples/actions/confirmation.php" method="post">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Login to Your Account</h4>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required="required">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="required">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group small clearfix">
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
                <a href="#" class="forgot-link">Forgot Password?</a>
              </div>
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" value="Login">
            </form>
            <!-- <form class="form-horizontal" action='' method="POST">
                  <fieldset>
                    <div id="legend">
                      <legend class="">Login</legend>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">

                      <label class="control-label"  for="username">Username</label>
                      <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">

                      <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>
                      <div class="controls">
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">

                      <div class="controls">
                        <button id="formButton" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </fieldset>
            </form>-->
           </div>
<BR>
          <div id="menuOptions" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Mis pedidos</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Gestionar pedidos</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Gestionar categorias</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- CONTINGUT CENTRAL -->
        <div id="central" class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
          <!-- TÍTOL -->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <h1>Feature Products</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- PRODUCTES -->
          <div id="divProductes" class="row">

            <div class="product col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 card">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="img/emarket-favicon.png"/ >
              <div class="card-body">
                <h2 class="card-title">PC GAMER</h2>
                <p class="card-title">900€</p>
              <a class="btn btn-success" href="#">Comprar</a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="product col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 card">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="img/emarket-favicon.png"/ >
              <div class="card-body">
                <h2 class="card-title">PC GAMER</h2>
                <p class="card-title">900€</p>
              <a class="btn btn-success" href="#">Comprar</a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="product col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 card">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="img/emarket-favicon.png"/ >
              <div class="card-body">
                <h2 class="card-title">PC GAMER</h2>
                <p class="card-title">900€</p>
              <a class="btn btn-success" href="#">Comprar</a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="product col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 card">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="img/emarket-favicon.png"/ >
              <div class="card-body">
                <h2 class="card-title">PC GAMER</h2>
                <p class="card-title">900€</p>
              <a class="btn btn-success" href="#">Comprar</a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="product col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 card">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="img/emarket-favicon.png"/ >
              <div class="card-body">
                <h2 class="card-title">PC GAMER</h2>
                <p class="card-title">900€</p>
              <a class="btn btn-success" href="#">Comprar</a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="product col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 card">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="img/emarket-favicon.png"/ >
              <div class="card-body">
                <h2 class="card-title">PC GAMER</h2>
                <p class="card-title">900€</p>
              <a class="btn btn-success" href="#">Comprar</a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="product col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 card">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="img/emarket-favicon.png"/ >
              <div class="card-body">
                <h2 class="card-title">PC GAMER</h2>
                <p class="card-title">900€</p>
              <a class="btn btn-success" href="#">Comprar</a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="product col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 card">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="img/emarket-favicon.png"/ >
              <div class="card-body">
                <h2 class="card-title">PC GAMER</h2>
                <p class="card-title">900€</p>
              <a class="btn btn-success" href="#">Comprar</a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!--<div class="product col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <img src="img/emarket-favicon.png"/>
              <h2>iPad Pro</h2>
              <p>650€</p>
              <a href="#">Comprar</a>
            </div>
            <div class="product col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <img src="img/emarket-favicon.png"/>
              <h2>Huawei Watch 2000</h2>
              <p>350€</p>
              <a href="#">Comprar</a>
            </div>
            <div class="product col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <img src="img/emarket-favicon.png"/>
              <h2>iPhone 11 256GB</h2>
              <p>1.500€</p>
              <a href="#">Comprar</a>
            </div>-->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- PEU DE PÀGINA -->
      <div class="row">
        <div id="footer" class="col-12">
          <p>Desenvolupat per Alex Iglesias i Isaac Labuena &copy; <?=date("Y") ?></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* GENERAL*/

*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

body{
    background: url(../img/fondo1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}

.h1-logo {
  margin:auto;
  line-height:50px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

a {
    color: #01b1ea;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited{
    color: #01b1ea;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover{
    color: #555;
}

.container{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px gray;
}

/* CAPÇALERA */

#header{
    background: #f0f0f0;
}

#logo{
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

#logo img {
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
}

#logo a{
    float: left;
    font-size: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #01b1ea;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 18px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 1px #222222;
    transition: all 300ms;
}

#logo a:hover{
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 1px #222222, 0px 0px 4px #01b1ea;
}

/* MENU */

#menu{
    width: 100%;
}

/* LOGIN */

#login {
  text-align: center;
}

/*#formButton {
  display: inline-block;
}*/

.card-img-top, .card-body, .card-title {
  margin: 0px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

/* PRODUCTES */

#divProductes {
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.product img {
    width: 100px;
}

/* CONTINGUT CENTRAL */

#content{
    background: white;
}

/* HOLLAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA */

body {
        color: #999;
        background: #f5f5f5;
        font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
    }
    .form-control {
        box-shadow: none;
        border-color: #ddd;
    }
    .form-control:focus {
        border-color: #4aba70;
    }
    .login-form {
        width: 350px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 30px 0;
    }
    .login-form form {
        color: #434343;
        border-radius: 1px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        background: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
        box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        padding: 30px;
    }
    .login-form h4 {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 22px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .login-form .avatar {
        color: #fff;
        margin: 0 auto 30px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        z-index: 9;
        background: #4aba70;
        padding: 15px;
        box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
    .login-form .avatar i {
        font-size: 62px;
    }
    .login-form .form-group {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .login-form .form-control, .login-form .btn {
        min-height: 40px;
        border-radius: 2px;
        transition: all 0.5s;
    }
    .login-form .close {
        position: absolute;
        top: 15px;
        right: 15px;
    }
    .login-form .btn {
        background: #4aba70;
        border: none;
        line-height: normal;
    }
    .login-form .btn:hover, .login-form .btn:focus {
        background: #42ae68;
    }
    .login-form .checkbox-inline {
        float: left;
    }
    .login-form input[type="checkbox"] {
        margin-top: 2px;
    }
    .login-form .forgot-link {
        float: right;
    }
    .login-form .small {
        font-size: 13px;
    }
    .login-form a {
        color: #4aba70;
    }
```

El problema ahora viene cuando redimensiono el tamaño de la ventana de tal manera que está entre móvil y tablet, más o menos a los píxeles que aparecen en la siguiente imagen (en el espacio blanco debería de salir la otra tarjetita porqué exist espacio, pero no sale ...).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En fin, muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Archivos: https://anonfile.com/n6n71d17o1/emarket_zip

Comment: Me parece te falta esta etiqueta en tu HTML: **`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1>`**

Comment: No he usado mucho el GridLayout de CSS (de hecho solo he visto un par de tutoriales por youtube), pero ¿no tienes que ponerle "display: grid" en el elemento padre?

Comment: @SJuan76 es que según veo usa booststrap, entonces con la clase `container` lo logra, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: Vale, he metido al viewport que me han comentado arriba y parece que me soluciona la vista en móvil.
Ahora tengo el siguiente problema que edito mi pregunta para que lo veáis.